# Django/Python: How to change filename when saving file using models.FileField?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I found this example to upload a file using FileField and it works great.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Problem is that it saves the original filename of the file being uploaded. I don't want that. I can change the filename within models.py by overriding the save function (see below). For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to pass a filename in when I execute form.save() from views.py. I need to know the filename for another process. I thought about even returning a filename from the models.py save function. I'm a bit of a noob so forgive any missing details. I've searched this site and read loads of documentation, but I'm missing something. Any advice would be appreciated.

Forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 50}))

class Meta:
    model = Document
    fields = ('description', 'document', )
```

Models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
document = models.FileField(upload_to='atlasapp/documents/')
uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    randomNum = random.randint(10000,90000)
    new_name = str(randomNum) + ".txt"
    self.document.name = new_name
    super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Views.py

```
def model_form_upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('model_form_upload')
else:
    form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you perhaps call `save()` on the form with `commit=False`, set the name on the `Document` file, and then save the `Document`? For example:

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.name = 'some_new_name'
            document.save()
            return redirect('model_form_upload')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You are THE man! I had to make a couple of changes, but this helped tremendously. I added documentfilename to my Document Class. Then modified your document.name suggestion to document.documentfilename = msgID + ".txt". Thank you again!!!